# How to get file path from JavaFX FileChooser?

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

I have a simple JavaFX window with a TextField for users to enter a file path and a separate browse link.

[JavaFX Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQCjq.jpg)

[image]

I'd like to ask how to extract the full file path of the selected file from JavaFX FileChooser (so I can set the path in the TextField)?

I understand what I'm trying to achieve can be done simply with Swing JFileChooser with something like:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
String someString = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
```

But since my application is in JavaFX I want it to have a consistent look and not a mix with Swing.

I've looked through the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a method for this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's another [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/file-chooser.htm). What you get in return from using [showOpenDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html#showOpenDialog-javafx.stage.Window-) is a [File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html?is-external=true) object.

> public File showOpenDialog(Window ownerWindow)
>
> Shows a new file open dialog. The method doesn't return until the
>   displayed open dialog is dismissed. The return value specifies the
>   file chosen by the user or null if no selection has been made. If the
>   owner window for the file dialog is set, input to all windows in the
>   dialog's owner chain is blocked while the file dialog is being shown.

A file object has various methods like e. g. [getAbsolutePath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath--).

Comment: Thank you so much sir, much appreciated, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 6):

Use `showOpenDialog` or `showSaveDialog` (depending on whether you want to open an existing file or save a new one). Both return a `File` object.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Will note that 'showSaveDialog' works also.

Comment: @Hans: `showSaveDialog` is likely not what you want in this case, since it allows the user to *"create a new file"* (i.e. the file returned may not exist).

Answer (score 2):

In the controller class where you have the TextField you can create a method like so:

```
public void getTheUserFilePath() {

    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    fileChooser.setTitle("Upload File Path");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("ALL FILES", "*.*"),
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("ZIP", "*.zip"),
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PDF", "*.pdf"),
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("TEXT", "*.txt"),
            new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("IMAGE FILES", "*.jpg", "*.png", "*.gif")
    );


    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(dialogPane.getScene().getWindow());

    if (file != null) {
        // pickUpPathField it's your TextField fx:id
        pickUpPathField.setText(file.getPath());

    } else  {
        System.out.println("error"); // or something else
    }

}
```